# Retrieve Component Service COM+ Application configuration values

Tags: powershell, com

I have a Component Service Application which values need to be retrieved by a powershell script, I've managed to get some configurations like the Pooling & Recycling values with the following script

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.EnterpriseServices"
$comAdmin = New-Object -ComObject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
$applications = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")
$applications.Populate()
foreach ($app in $applications) {
    $appName = $app.Name
    Write-Output "Application Name: $appName"
    # Retrieve recycling properties
    $recycleLifetimeLimit = $app.Value("RecycleLifetimeLimit")
    $recycleMemoryLimit = $app.Value("RecycleMemoryLimit")
    $recycleCallLimit = $app.Value("RecycleCallLimit")
    $recycleActivationLimit = $app.Value("RecycleActivationLimit")
    $recycleExpirationTimeout = $app.Value("RecycleExpirationTimeout")
    # Output recycling properties
    Write-Output "  RecycleLifetimeLimit: $recycleLifetimeLimit"
    Write-Output "  RecycleMemoryLimit: $recycleMemoryLimit"
    Write-Output "  RecycleCallLimit: $recycleCallLimit"
    Write-Output "  RecycleActivationLimit: $recycleActivationLimit"
    Write-Output "  RecycleExpirationTimeout: $recycleExpirationTimeout"
    Write-Output "-------------------------"
}
```

But I want to retrieve the "Remote Server Name" that is located in the "Activation" Tab showed in the image bellow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olUYw.png)